# IIS basic authentication and Active directory

Tags: iis, active-directory, ldap, basic-authentication

I am trying to figure out how to set the default domain in IIS when choosing basic authentication. I have an LDAP string but I'm quite clueless as to how to extract the information I need from it for setting the default domain setting.

When I programatically connect to an Active directory I use the string:

DirectoryEntry _entry = new DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://xx.xx.xx.xx/CN=Users,DC=dc1,DC=dc2,DC=dc3", "user", "password");

What information do I need to pull from this string for the default domain setting in IIS?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from the (sanitized) LDAP string you gave, your Windows Active Directory domain would be like dc1.dc2.dc3--say if dc1 is "site", dc2 is "company", and dc3 is "net" then the domain is "site.company.net".

Or on a command prompt you could type `echo %USERDNSDOMAIN%` and see the same thing.